Bizarre Issue with decimals and leading zeros in BizTalk EDI Batching Validation
We're running into a very strange issue with our installation of BizTalk Server 2013R2. For only one party, we cannot process EDI messages that have elements with amounts that are decimal with values less than 1; like 0.00 or 0.50, etc.
The messages suspend with the error "Invalid character in data element". Here is an example of the full error:
Exception thrown from segment 2, progress 33

Inner exception: The batch is being suspended as it either failed schema validation or context properties are not matching batch definition. 

Error: 1 (Field level error)  
SegmentID: HI   
Data element ID: C02205_ValueCodeAmount   
Position in Segment: 3   
Position in Field: 5   
Data Value: 0.00    
6: Invalid character in data element

I have reviewed the agreement settings over and over, and I don't understand where this is coming from. In the "Validation" screen of the "Transaction Set Settings" section, I verified that "Leading and trailing spaces and zeros policy" is set to "Allowed". I also confirmed in the XML schema that the element is setup as an xs:string, which should be fine with a decimal character.
The most bizarre thing is that other parties send this type of data, and it works fine. So I have to think it is something with the agreement that's not setup right, but I poured over every setting and I can't find what it could be.
Any ideas, suggestions or help would be appreciated!

Have you seen this article:   FIX: Validation fails on the EDI send pipeline when you process EDI messages that contain leading and trailing zeros and spaces in BizTalk Server
To me it seem the issue description in the above article seems to match your problem. Have you applied CU1 to your Biztalk Server 2013R2 instance, as suggested in the article?

We found that support article as well. While the behavior being described is exactly what we're seeing, the server is at patch level CU7. It is strange, though, that it's the exact same thing we're seeing happen.

@c_tothe_k Maybe the issue has regressed in a later CU. As BizTalk 2013 R2 is out of extended support, there probably won't be a fix coming from Microsoft, even if you rais it with them.  You might have to start considering upgrading to BizTalk 2020.
